# How to create a prestashop module that triggers codeon add/edit/delete products/categories

Tags: prestashop

I am currently new to prestashop.

I managed to build a simple module (in prestashop 1.7), but I also want my module to trigger some code when a product or category is changed/added/deleted.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectModel calls this after every add:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.$this->getFullyQualifiedName().'AddAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

and every update:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.$this->getFullyQualifiedName().'UpdateAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

and every deletion:

```
Hook::exec('actionObject'.$this->getFullyQualifiedName().'DeleteAfter', array('object' => $this));
```

So hook to `actionObjectProductAddAfter`, `actionObjectProductUpdateAfter` and `actionObjectProductDeleteAfter` for products, and the same for categories.

Comment: It worked, thanks!
I registered the hook upon installation and created the method for the hook

Comment: @AndreiSilveanu Mark the answer as solved if it worked.